# Remove wpautop from retrieve_password_message

Tags: email

I have been struggling to remove the `wpautop` filter from the `retrieve_password_message` function. I created a new email message and want to keep my `<br>`s instead of having automatic paragraphs added - since most email clients can't handle well `<p>` paddings or margins.

Any help?

Comment: I'm looking at the source code, and as far as I can tell `wpautop` is not applied to `retrieve_password_message`. In fact, the password reset email does not even appear to be an HTML email, so HTML tags wouldn't even work.

Comment: Well in fact it does add the p tags... I looked the source code myself, that’s why I’m here :)

Comment: Source code of what `wpautop()`? I know, but where is it applied to the password reset email?

Comment: I checked the file where the wpautop filter is applied and there is no indication about emails. If you try the retrieve function though, it adds the tags :/

Comment: How do you know this is happening? If you’re inspecting the email in a web mail client then it’s more than likely added by the client so that it can render a plain text email in the browser.

Comment: Actually i didn’t think about this - I’ll check and report back. The thing is that other emails sent using wp_mail don’t render with additional p tags. Currently afk, I will check later and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the constructive conversation with Jacob in the comments, I did some additional tests and realized that the `<p>` tags were in fact added by the plugin - testing in ive environment revealed that the email was plain text.

The solution to the problem was to add the following snippet in my `functions.php`:

```
function email_set_content_type(){
  return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','email_set_content_type' );
```